# Google Map Direction Service Location Not Found

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two select button the have the value for latitude and longitude. The problem is when I choose an option the location is not found. How can I show a direction freely by just using the latitude and longitude? I am using PHP to show the lat and long of the locations.

My Code:

```
<div id="distance-panel">
                    <h3>Start: </h3>
                    <select id="start">
                        <?php
                            include "connect.php";

                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblLocation";
                            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                echo "
                                    <option value='{lat:".$row['latitude'].",lng:".$row['longitude']."}'>".$row['branch']."</option>
                                ";
                            }
                            mysqli_close($conn);
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <h3>End: </h3>
                    <select id="end">
                        <?php
                            include "connect.php";

                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblLocation";
                            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                echo "
                                    <option value='{lat:".$row['latitude'].",lng:".$row['longitude']."}'>".$row['branch']."</option>
                                ";
                            }
                            mysqli_close($conn);
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="distance-map"></div>
                <script>
                          function initMap() {
                            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
                            var uluru = {lat: 13, lng: 122};
                            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
                            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('distance-map'), {
                              zoom: 5.2,
                              center: uluru
                            });
                            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

                            var onChangeHandler = function() {
                              calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
                            };
                            document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
                            document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
                          }

                          function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
                            directionsService.route({
                              origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
                              destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
                              travelMode: 'DRIVING'
                            }, function(response, status) {
                              if (status === 'OK') {
                                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                              } else {
                                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                              }
                            });
                          }
                    </script>
                    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDd03Su-LQGB3ZVB3MvP1a3q01lrgAvqlE&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), does `directionsService.route` expect origin and destination to be **strings** in the form `"{lat: 12.34, lng: 12.34}"` ? (hint: no, it does not accept such values)

Comment: @JaromandaX What can I do to make this work?

Comment: follow the documentation

Comment: @JaromandaX I used LatLng values but still error why?

Comment: you used a string - read the doucmentation

Comment: How can I convert it to a LatLng?

Comment: Im still new to this please guide me

Comment: OK .. in the markup you'll want `<option value="12.34,12.34" .... etc ...>` that may work, not sure - I'm sure you can change the php to do that

Comment: I've done it now what's next?

Comment: I take it that didn't work if you ask what's next - wasn't sure it would though, the documentation says that if the value you pass to origin and destination is a **string**, it's a string representing a location ... like `"Sydney, Australia"` not sure `151,-33` would work ... does the HTML produced look valid?

Comment: Wha i did is I change my php then i used  new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('start').value)

Comment: what does the value look like, in the markup, i.e. in the browser

Comment: When I used alert the value is like this 151,-33

Comment: @JaromandaX what do i do to fix this :(

Comment: nevermind I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the value and convert each value to float.

```
var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
var o_split = start.split(',');
var o_lat = parseFloat(o_split[0]);
var o_lng = parseFloat(o_split[1]);

var end  = document.getElementById('end').value;
var d_split = end.split(',');
var d_lat = parseFloat(d_split[0]);
var d_lng = parseFloat(d_split[1]);
```

And change origin and destination to,

```
 origin: {lat: o_lat,lng: o_lng},
 destination:  {lat: d_lat,lng: d_lng},
```

Answer (score 0):

Directions accept strings like `41.878114,-87.629798` for origin and destination. They don't have to be objects like `{lat:41.878114,lng:-87.629798}`.

So, you just need to change your PHP code to this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "
<option value='".$row['latitude'].",".$row['longitude']."'>".$row['branch']."</option>
"; //<option value='41.878114,-87.629798'>Chicago</option>
}
```

And that's all. :D

Here's a working sample using just the string version: http://jsbin.com/cucuzin/edit?html,css,js,output

(Note that I used the same JS code that you have provided in your question and it's working)